# Put current section number in name of thereom-like environment

Tags: sectioning, theorems, thmtools

The following source numbers exercises consecutively across sections. It successfully adds, for each exercise set,an entry to the table of contents that includes the current section number.

**Question:** How do I get the name "EXERCISES FOR SECTION 0" for each exercise set to show, in fact, the current section number?

The part `\thesection` of the parameter `name={EXERCISES FOR SECTION~\thesection}`, in the `problemscontent` theorem-like environment is not getting the actual current section number.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
%the
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headformat=\NAME\NOTE,
    headfont= \sffamily\bfseries,
    headpunct={\vspace{\topsep}\newline},
    numbered=no,
    spaceabove= 3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,postheadspace=0pt    
]{probs}
%
\declaretheorem[
  name={EXERCISES FOR SECTION~\thesection},
  style=probs,
  preheadhook={\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Exercises for Section~\thesection}}
]{problemscontent}
%
\newenvironment{problemset}
{\problemscontent}
{\endproblemscontent}

\usepackage{enumitem}
%
\newlist{problems}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[problems,1]{%
    label=\bfseries\sffamily\arabic*.,
    ref={\arabic*},
    before=\leavevmode \vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topsep\relax}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\begin{problemset}
  \begin{problems}[series=probs]
    \item First problem.
    \item Second problem.
  \end{problems}
\end{problemset}

\section{Details}

\begin{problemset}
  \begin{problems}[resume*=probs]
    \item A new exercise.
  \end{problems}
\end{problemset}

\end{document}
```

[image: Section numbers needed in EXERCISES name]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If want to expand `\thesection` not while declaring the *theorem* but while using it, you have to protect `\thesection`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm,thmtools}
%the
\declaretheoremstyle[
    headformat=\NAME\NOTE,
    headfont= \sffamily\bfseries,
    headpunct={\vspace{\topsep}\newline},
    numbered=no,
    spaceabove= 3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex,postheadspace=0pt    
]{probs}
%
\declaretheorem[
  name={EXERCISES FOR SECTION~\protect\thesection},% CHANGED
  style=probs,
  preheadhook={\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Exercises for Section~\thesection}}
]{problemscontent}
%
\newenvironment{problemset}
{\problemscontent}
{\endproblemscontent}

\usepackage{enumitem}
%
\newlist{problems}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[problems,1]{%
    label=\bfseries\sffamily\arabic*.,
    ref={\arabic*},
    before=\leavevmode \vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip+\topsep\relax}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\begin{problemset}
  \begin{problems}[series=probs]
    \item First problem.
    \item Second problem.
  \end{problems}
\end{problemset}

\section{Details}

\begin{problemset}
  \begin{problems}[resume*=probs]
    \item A new exercise.
  \end{problems}
\end{problemset}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I'm asking myself: Why using a theorem like environment, instead of just extending `problems` by a heading?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
%
\newlist{problems}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[problems,1]{%
    label=\bfseries\sffamily\arabic*.,
    ref={\arabic*},
    before=\problemsheading}
\newcommand*{\problemsheading}{%
  \subsection*{\sffamily EXERCISES FOR SECTION~\thesection}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Exercises for Section~\thesection}
}
  
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{Introduction}

\begin{problems}[series=probs]
\item First problem.
\item Second problem.
\end{problems}

\section{Details}

\begin{problems}[resume*=probs]
\item A new exercise.
\end{problems}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To decrease the size of the exercises headings, you can either replace `\subsection*` by `\subsubsection*` or add a font size command to `\sffamily`. Or you can use package `titlesec` to configure the heading of subsections.

Comment: The reason for using the theorem-like environment `problemset` is to allow convenient use of `cleveref` and `crossreftools` for cross-references to problems, and parts of problems, and in such a way that references to problems in a given section have such form as "Exercise 3" within a given section but such form as "Exercise 5.3" when the target is in a different section.

Comment: @cabohan: I'm still checking that everything is OK for my actual, book-length (`memoir` doc class) document, but I think I can use your `enumitem` method ... *provided that* in the `setlist` command the `\addcontentsline` line is omitted and the `\subsection*...` line is changed to `\subsection[Exercises for Section~\thesection]{\sffamily EXERCISES FOR SECTION~\thesection}`. This seems to make the entries OK (not all in upper case) in both the top-level TOC and in chapter TOCs provided by `etoc`.

Comment: @murray Using `\subsection` instead of `\subsection*` can result in subsection numbers depending on counter `secnumdepth`. Your question asked for not numbered headings for the exercises (resp. using the section number only instead of the subsection counter). That's the reason why I've used `\subsection*`.  BTW: If there are issues using another class and additional packages not shown in the current question, please feel free to ask a follow-up question with a corresponding MWE.

Comment: Yes, I don't want the exercises numbered like a subsection. But using `\subsection[Exercises for Section~\thesection]{\sffamily EXERCISES FOR SECTION~\thesection}` does *not* produce a subsection number. I leave `secnumdepth1 at its default under `memoir`.

Comment: Oops: using just the `enumitem` bit me: I have instances where, within a single problem set, I interrupt the enumeration to insert some text (about the following several problems) and then resume the enumeration. Alas, using `\begin{problems}[resume]` there emits a spurious new "Exercises for Section x.x" heading and a corresponding spurious new entry in the table of contents!

Comment: The "interruption" situation can be handled, though: after `\end{problems}` and the intervening text, the list must be resumed with `\begin{problems}[resume,before={}]`. So this situation is doable, too, using the `enumitem` method.